# Error while getting value from EditText?

Tags: android, paypal, android-edittext

I am Integrating paypal in my App.I need to get the amount from the `Edittext`.
I tried it with String type but the `PayPalPayment` method is in BigDecimal.
It is throwing error

`The Constructor BigDecimal(BigDecimal) is undefined`

So please correct me ...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donate);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    startService(intent);
}

public void onBuyPressed(View pressed)
{       
EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amtdon);
    BigDecimal amt = (BigDecimal) amount.getText();
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(amt), "USD", "Donate Remote IT ", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You are getting the `amt` in `onCreate()` so, unless you have a default value there, it will be empty and give you a parsing error. Move it to your button click method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you need replace

```
BigDecimal amt = (BigDecimal) amount.getText();
```

to

```
BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal(amount.getText().toString());
```

**Updated**

replace

```
EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amtdon);
BigDecimal amt = (BigDecimal) amount.getText();
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(amt), "USD", "Donate Remote IT ", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

to

```
EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amtdon);
BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal(amount.getText().toString());
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(atm, "USD", "Donate Remote IT ", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

Comment: Throwing The Constructor BigDecimal(BigDecimal) is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try to do Like this

```
BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal(amount.getText().toString);
```

Comment: Throwing The Constructor BigDecimal(BigDecimal) is undefined

Comment: After running you are getting..what is ur input in edidtext